# Is there a correct way to click on a component tag to scroll to that page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

So basically my page consists of several components. For e.g

HomePage.vue

```
<component1 id = "c1"/>
<component2 id = "c2"/>
<component3 id = "c3"/>
```

I would like my Navigation bar to scroll to the particular component when I click on it. For e.g

TopNav.vue

```
<b-nav-item href = "#c1">component1</b-nav-item>
<b-nav-item href = "#c2">component2</b-nav-item>
<b-nav-item href = "#c3">component3</b-nav-item>
```

Currently, I am using href = id for it to scroll. However, this function does not work properly on my iPhone and iPad (though it works on my windows computer). Is there a proper or correct way to scroll to the component?

I try not to use window.scrollTo(x,y) because it is difficult for me to find the exact location I want for x and y. I believe there is an easier way for me to scroll to the component I want.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

For eg.:

```
var element = document.getElementById("box");
element.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: Hi @TJ, thank you for your answer. I am able to navigate with my mobile now. However, the smooth scrolling effect does not work on phone. Do you happen to know why? For my smooth scrolling effect, I did using html {scrolling-behavior: smooth;}

Comment: Try this form: `element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});`

Comment: Hi @TJ thank you for your reply. It still doesn't work with the code given above. Thank you for your help tho! :)